# How can I programatically change the color of node title in views results?

Tags: 7

I want to change the color of the node titles from a view (fields on table).
My first ides was to alter the title and add a span with inline css.

```
function views_titles_views_pre_render(&$view) {
if ($view->name == 'documents' && $view->current_display == 'page') {
    $span_open  = '<span style="color: green !important;">';
    $span_close = '</span>';
    $view->style_plugin->render_fields($view->result);
    foreach ($view->style_plugin->rendered_fields as $index => &$rendered_result) {
      // Add HTML markup icon on rendered title field
      $rendered_result['title'] = $span_open . $rendered_result['title'].$span_close;
    }
  }
}
```

Although my attempt was a success, I managed to alter the title the css rule did not alter the color of the a tag. I figured out that I should go deeper into the title. As far I can tel the dpm of the views_pre_render does not show more options.

I have experience with drupal site building, but I am not in any way a php developer.

Can someone help me figure this out?

ps: I know there other more easy ways to achieve that but I want to do it with a module.

Comment: If you want to do it with a module, you can do it by simply adding a css files in a module.

Answer (score 1):

An easier (and more maintainable) way to achieve this would be to set a class in your span, instead of hardcoding the style. Something like the following:

```
$span_open = '<span class="my-title">"';
```

You can then add a CSS file to your module, so that you can better specify the color, also overriding the `a` tag. For instance:

```
.my-title, .my-title a {
  color: green;
}
```

For more details about adding CSS to your module, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x